# Why is 'self' used outside of a class?

Tags: swift, swift3, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

I'm following [this tutorial on GitHub](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox) on how to implement SwiftyDropbox in an iOS app. There's a point where it tells me to add this code to my ViewController

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyDropbox

func myButtonInControllerPressed()
{
    DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromController(UIApplication.shared, controller: self, openURL: { (url: URL) -> Void in UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)})
}
```

I then get an error saying

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'self'
```

Presumably this is because I'm declaring a function outside of a class. What am I doing wrong? Does anyone know of a tutorial/sample-app that actually works and is up to date with the latest Swift and Xcode that could teach me how to use SwiftyDropbox?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox/issues/142 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph before that snippet does say

> You can commence the auth flow by calling `authorizeFromController:controller:openURL:browserAuth` method in your **application's view controller**.

[image]

So it is telling you to write that snippet **INSIDE** your View Controller (where using `self` makes sense).

Here's an example

```
class Controller: UIViewController {

    func myButtonInControllerPressed() {
        DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromController(UIApplication.shared,
                                                      controller: self,
                                                      openURL: { (url: URL) -> Void in
                                                        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        })
    }

}
```